# Problema de CORS con React, express y API externa

Tags: reactjs, api, express, cors

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta a una API externa, un GET. Pero todo el tiempo obtengo el siguiente mensaje

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.search?q_track=hola&page_size=12&s_track_rating=desc&apikey=value' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Sé que es un problema de CORS, pero no sé cómo solucionarlo. He probado de todo

He probado añadirle CORS a express, con todas estas opciones.

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: true | false | dominio_de_la_API | localhost:3000 etc
}))
```

Estoy usando AXIOS para hacer las peticiones desde el front, con la siguiente configuración (con y sin headers):

```
const options = {
  params: {
    apikey: "valor de la API",
  },
};

export const searchTrack = (songName, sort) =>
  instance.get(
    `track.search?q_track=${songName}&page_size=12&s_track_rating=${sort}`,
    options
  );
```

He probado mil cosas, cambiado mil valores y variables, hasta he modificado el devServer de webpack para enviar las cabeceras desde allí.

Entiendo que no es un problema de CORS desde mi APP, si no que tiene que haber algo que estoy haciendo mal porque:

- Si utilizo la extensión para habilitar CORS en chrome, funciona la petición.
- Si hago un peticióndirecta con el navegador a la URL + API KEY, funciona.
- Si hago una petición con Postman, funciona.

Este es mi server.js que es el que crea la instancia de express y sirve React con SSR:

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import webpack from "webpack";
import helmet from "helmet";
import React from "react";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import { renderRoutes } from "react-router-config";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Layout } from "components";
import serverRoutes from "../frontend/routes/serverRoutes";
import getManifest from "./getManifest";

dotenv.config();

const { ENV, PORT_DEV, PORT_PRO } = process.env;
const port = ENV === "development" ? PORT_DEV : PORT_PRO;

const app = express();

if (ENV === "development") {
  console.log("#########################################");
  console.log("Enviroment: ", "Working on develop");

  const webpackConfig = require("../../webpack.config");
  const webpackDevMiddleware = require("webpack-dev-middleware");
  const webpackHotMiddleware = require("webpack-hot-middleware");
  const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

  const serverConfig = {
    port: PORT_DEV,
    hot: true,
  };

  app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, serverConfig));
  app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
}

if (ENV === "production") {
  app.use((request, response, next) => {
    if (!request.hashManifest) {
      request.hashManifest = getManifest();
    }
    next();
  });
  app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));
  app.use(helmet());
  app.use(helmet.permittedCrossDomainPolicies());
  app.disable("x-powered-by");
}

const setResponse = (html, manifest) => {
  const mainStyles = manifest ? manifest["main.css"] : "assets/main.css";
  const mainBuild = manifest ? manifest["main.js"] : "assets/main.js";
  const vendorBuild = manifest ? manifest["vendors.js"] : "assets/vendor.js";

  return `
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="es">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8" />
          <link href="${mainStyles}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
          <title>React App</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="root">${html}</div>
          <script src="${mainBuild}" type="text/javascript"></script>
          <script src="${vendorBuild}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </body>
      </html>
    `;
};

const renderApp = (request, response) => {
  const html = renderToString(
    <Layout>
      <StaticRouter location={request.url} context={{}}>
        {renderRoutes(serverRoutes)}
      </StaticRouter>
    </Layout>
  );

  response.send(setResponse(html, request.hashManifest));
};

app.get("*", renderApp);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Error: ", "can not run the server.");
  } else {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port} - ${ENV}`);
    console.log("#########################################");
  }
});
```

Cómo hago la petición

```
searchTrack(search, sort)
 .then((response) =>
   response.status === 200 && setTrackList(response.data.message.body.track_list))
 .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Dudas que me surgen:

1. Al ser server side rendering ¿express debe responder con algunas cabeceras?
2. ¿debería hacer las peticiones desde express en lugar desde la parte del front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el navegador no aceptará hacer peticiones al dominio `api.musixmatch.com` porque éste no implementa CORS.

**No puedes solucionarlo directamente** pero, como comentas, puedes delegar la petición a tu backend y de este modo evitarlo.

> ¿debería hacer las peticiones desde express en lugar desde la parte del front?

Es una solución. Pero si quieres consumir el API sin sobrecargar tu Node.js, puedes poner delante un Apache/Nginx funcionando como proxy inverso (redireccionando las peticiones directamente, sin pasar por `express`)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Desconocía que podía poner un servidor por delante como proxy. Por último: ¿hay alguna forma certera de saber si un endpoint, dominio, servidor implementa CORS?

Comment: Si no tienes acceso al código o a alguna documentación, no. Sólo prueba y error